# How is "using" statement supposed to work?

Tags: c#, .net, using

I'm trying to take advantage of the `using` statement in the following code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:50222/odata"); 
var container = new CourseServiceRef.Container(uri);

CourseServiceRef.NotNeeded newTempUser = new CourseServiceRef.NotNeeded()
    { 
       Email = model.UserName,
       Username1 = model.UserName 
    };             
container.AddToNotNeededs(newTempUser);
container.SaveChanges();
```

However this doesn't compile. Why?

Comment: What do you want to be "using"?

Comment: Thank you everyone for replies...mason, I want to use using as the objects are disposed of after they have been used, and using includes try catch

Comment: I know why/how to use the `using` statement. But you have not made it clear what you intend to use it on. None of us can tell which of your classes implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Steve which classes within this code are implementing `IDisposable`? I could update my answer with an example that relates to your code.

Comment: Thanks Crono. I will take a look. I understand some classes implement iDisposable 'out the box' (ie in the framework). I was hoping a service reference call such as mine would implement iDisposable out the box.

Comment: @Steve it depends on what a service "reference" is. If you mean a value returned by a service, then it likely isn't implementing `IDisposable` because, well, it doesn't need to. Sometimes the variable going out of scope is enough for resources to be properly released. I suggest you read more about IDisposable role within .NET Framework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) - not to be mingled with [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) - is meant for objects that implement the [`IDisposable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) so that they're disposed of automatically at the end of the code block:

```
using (var toto = new MyDisposableClass())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

If any of your classes do implement this interface (or inherit from something that does), you may use the above syntax to ensure call to `Dispose()` method. You cannot use `using` blocks for objects that does not implement this interface, it simply won't compile.

Essentially, this will be doing the same as the following:

```
var toto = new MyDisposableClass()

try
{
    // do stuff
}
finally
{
    if (toto != null) ((IDisposable)toto).Dispose();
}
```

The only difference here would be that in the first scenario, `toto`'s scope dies at the end of the `using` block.

Comment: I would also add that if you try to use using on an object that does not implement `IDisposable` your code will not compile

Comment: Small nit, if need to change the last line of your example to `((IDisposeable)toto).Dispose();`, some classes implement `IDisposeable` explicity so you can use them in a `using` statement but you can't call `Dispose()` directly on them. If the OP is working with [`ClientBase<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms576141(v=vs.100).aspx) (The base class auto generated WCF classes use) it uses a [explicitly implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340248(v=vs.100).aspx) `Dispose()`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I ended up editing my answer, but IMHO implicit / explicit interface implementation is a bit out of scope here. :)

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of "using" is to ensure Dispose() is called on an object that implements IDisposable. Therefore, the best way to use using keyword in your code is, like in any other code, on objects that implement IDisposable. This could be, for example, your "newTempUser" or your "container". Since we do not have access to their definitions, only you can answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't really good and bad uses of `using`. Either you use it or you don't. If you don't use it when instantiating a class implementing `IDisposable` then you've likely made a mistake (unless you have some good reason for calling `Dispose` yourself elsewhere which is a very small percent of use cases).

If you fail to use it then the point when the resource is disposed of is less predictable and it will likely have negative effects on your applications performance. There aren't different ways of using it, there is only one;

```
using (ClassImplementigIDisposable instance = new ClassImplementigIDisposable()) 
{ 
     // code that uses instance
     // at the end of this block `Dispose` will be called on instance 
}
```